# c# send email trough other host than gmail

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I'm currently developing an app with c# and I want to send an email from a smtp host called '**smtp.online.nl**'. I'm using port **485** (as I saw on their tutorial how to configure a mail client) and everything seems to be correct.

Here is my code:

```
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add("testEmail@hotmail.com");
        message.Subject = "C# generated message!";
        message.From = new MailAddress("mySendemailAddress@online.nl");
        message.Body = "This is the message body \r\nThis is a next line";
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions=DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.online.nl", 485);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials=new NetworkCredential("mySendEmailAddress@online.nl", "password");

        smtp.Send(message);
```

When I run this, the email won't be send and I got a `SmtpException: "Error sending e-mail".`

My question: is there anything wrong with my code? Any other idea's why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Issues with SMTP like this tend to be to do with the server more than your code.  Have you tried multiple usernames?  E.g. with and without the @online.nl.  Are you sure that the server uses SSL?

Comment: Thanks for you comment, yes I did try it without and with the @online.nl in the network credential. And about the SSL: the tutorial says the following: "Check the box that says on the server for **incoming** e-mail is SSL needed". I enabled an disabled this in my code: no effect unfortunately. Is it an idea to contact the company providing the webmail?

Comment: Have you tried disabling SSL and changing the Port to standard SMTP port (25)?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SMTP port to 25 (standard SMTP port) did the job. Thanks to Luke Park.